# Updating locations while app in background working on simulator but not on device (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, ios9, location-services

I have enabled `Background Modes > Location updates` in my target's capabilites. I run the app in an `iOS 9` simulator, I put the app in background state with `Location > City run` in the simulator, and it seems to keep getting location updates. But I run the app in a real `iOS 9` device and few seconds after going to background, I loose the location services arrow in the status bar and no location updates are received.

On the other hand, I've run the app in a real `iOS 8` device and it seems to keep listening for locations (the arrow in the status bar does not disappear).

Why are location services stopping in background in an `iOS 9` real `iPhone`?

I need help to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With iOS 9 you also need to set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `yes`.  See the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanx a lot. you saved my day